# Deserializing a non-standard json in GO

Tags: json, go, deserialization

I'm writing a simple app that makes requests to an API that returns a heterogeneous JSON of the type

```
{
  "results": [
    [123, "Zho's Mask", 10586],
    [345, "Ravaging Superior Studded Coat", 58]
  ]
}
```

Ultimately, I would want to be able to use specific indices from the result response. For example, I would want to be able to just get "Zho's Mask", or the price: 10586. Here is the API I am using [GW2TP](https://www.gw2tp.com/api).

Most of the examples in the GO JSON blogs make reference to simpler or straightforward JSON that does not include nested arrays.

From what I read, since I know the general look of the JSON response, I can make a GO struct and unmarshall it into an instance of the struct. However, I have not been able to create the correct struct for this job.

This is my current attempt at creating the appropriate struct

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

// {"results":[[123,"Zho's Mask",3532]]}

type Equipment struct {
    Results []ResArray
}

type ResArray struct {
    Medium []LastArray
}

type LastArray struct {
    Info string
}

func main() {
    res, err := http.Get("http://api.gw2tp.com/1/items?ids=123&fields=name,sell")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var equipment Equipment

    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("ReadAll Error: ", err, "\n")
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &equipment)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Print("Unmarshal error: ", err, "\n")
    }

}
```

This is the Unmarshal error:

```
Unmarshal error: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field Equipment.Results of type main.ResArray
```

Lastly, here is my inspiration for my current approach to this desired GO struct
[JSON in Golang an Introduction](https://medium.com/swlh/json-in-golang-an-introduction-8e889c29a83).

Comment: Use an `interface{}` instead of `string` or write you own unmarshal function.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/7IRu1DeoFee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> type ResArray struct {

but it's not a struct, it's a slice!

> ```
> type LastArray struct {
>     Info string
> }
> ```

but it's not a string, it's sometimes a string and sometimes a number.

The simple way to do this is to define your type as

```
type Equipment struct {
    Results [][]interface{}
}
```

which says that Results contains a slice of slices of... something. You could name the in-between types but it's not necessary. Then e.g. `e.Results[0][1].(string)` would be `"Zho's Mask"`.

The nicer way is to implement the [Unmarshaler](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface by providing a custom `UnmarshalJSON`, something like this:

```
type Equipment struct {
    Results []Item
}

type Item struct {
    ID int
    Name string
    Sell int
}

func (i *Item) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    // We're deserializing into a struct, but in JSON it's a mixed-type array.
    var arr []interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &arr)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("unmarshal Item underlying array: %w", err)
    }
    if len(arr) != 3 {
        return fmt.Errorf("Item underlying array should be 3 elements, got %d", len(arr))
    }

    // JSON numbers will become float64 when loaded into interface{} but we want int
    id, ok := arr[0].(float64)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("expected float64 for Item.ID, got %T", arr[0])
    }
    i.ID = int(id)

    i.Name, ok = arr[1].(string)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("expected string for Item.Name, got %T", arr[1])

    }

    sell, ok := arr[2].(float64)
    if !ok {
        return fmt.Errorf("expected float64 for Item.Sell, got %T", arr[2])
    }
    i.Sell = int(sell)
    return nil
}
```

bearing in mind that these types are married to the exact list of fields that you requested to the API — if you change that, you will have to change the type *and* the unmarshal function that loads it from the array.

Comment: Exactly the answer and explanation I was looking for!